# Spring Security getAuthentication() returns null

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm trying the return the currently logged in user from my Spring Boot + AngularJS application, but `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` returns null.

Security config:

```
@Configuration
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("test").password("test").roles("USER", "ADMIN");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .formLogin().and()
            .logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/index.html", "/login.html", "/").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
            .addFilterAfter(new CsrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class)
            .csrf().csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/bower_components/**");
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/js/**");
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/css/**");
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/api/user");
    }

    private static CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
        HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
        repository.setHeaderName("X-XSRF-TOKEN");
        return repository;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public User user() {
    User user = new User();
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    if (auth != null) {
        String name = auth.getName();
        user.setUsername(name);
    }
    return user;
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming that the controller you show is mapped to the context `/api/user`, then the reason is because you've added the line `web.ignoring().antMatchers("/api/user");` to your security configuration, which means that all requests to that controller are not secured, and thus also don't have a SecurityContext. Remove that line, so that Spring Security secures it.

Excerpt from the Javadoc of the ignoring method:

> Web Security provided by Spring Security (including the SecurityContext) will not be available on HttpServletRequest that match.

Answer (score 1):

Another reason might be you've spun up another thread to the original one requesting the resource.
That also happens when doing a `parallelStream().foreach`.

Comment: I was using a cron job that performs the tasks in different threads causing the SecurityContextHolder to return null each time. I handled it the other way. So, switching to another thread that requests the resource loses the SecurityContext... 
Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the `Authentication` object from a component class which is included in the Spring Security configuration you may use the following command.

```
Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()
```

For all the other cases, if you want to get the `Authentication` object, you may get it using the `HttpServletRequest` which is available to any class in the Spring Context.

```
Object sc = request.getSession().getAttribute(HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT_KEY);
if (!(sc instanceof SecurityContext)) {
    // Something strange is happening
}
Authentication authentication = ((SecurityContext) sc).getAuthentication();
```