# SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() returns null

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I'm developing Spring boot and security web application with authorization and resource servers enabled. I have defined a set of users with roles assigned to them and have implemented roles based access to rest endpoints. Besides that my application has straightforward UI with web pages. Those pages display the same data that is on rest. I'm trying to implement the same roles based access to pages with  `ResourceServerConfig#configure`  and my current code:

```
public void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/rest/products/add").hasAnyRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()

                .and().formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login.jsf").permitAll()
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/login-successful", true)
                .and().logout().permitAll();
    }
```

This configuration works perfectly for REST controllers access with bearer token, but authorization with the login form leads to the redirect to the  /login-successful  and  the message
**Full authentication is required to access this resourceunauthorized**   is displayed.

The reason is that `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` for */login-successful*  request in spite it was correctly initialized in `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter#successfulAuthentication`  at the point of login form post. The same issue with other web pages in my app as well.

What should be added to the above configuration so that make it work for the REST and form login bought ?

[Here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-login)  is indicted that  `HttpSecurity` configuration provided above is enough for authorization with form login to work correctly as far as `.anyRequest().authenticated()` should pass security context for all the resources in the application.

A similar case is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36411947/spring-security-getauthentication-returns-null) but the reason over there is that an url was explicitly ignored in `WebSecurity` configurer.

Comment: Try enabling `logger.level.org.springframework.security=trace` in `application.properties` to see what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in the fact that I was using deprecated `@EnableResourceServer` annotation that adds `OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter`. For the form login authorization flow this is incorrect and that filter was removing authentication object from the `SecurityContext`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41480102/how-spring-security-filter-chain-works) is indicated that `OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter` shouldn't present in the filter chain for the form login authorization flow.

The reason why I was needed `@EnableResourceServer` annotation is that there are there is the bearer authentication flow in my application alongside with form login.

I replaced `@EnableResourceServer` annotation and `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter` for the bearer authentication flow with Spring Security 5 resource server as `http.oauth2ResourceServer()` that is in `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`  ( [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54988935/spring-security-enableresourceserver-vs-oauth2resourceserver) ). Finally the solution is with the following two `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`-s:

For bearer authorization flow:

```
@Configuration
@Order(2)
public class SecurityConfigRest extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        NimbusJwtDecoder jwtDecoder = Build custom JWT decoder;

    http.csrf().disable()
            .requestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/rest/**"))
            .authorizeRequests()
            .mvcMatchers("/products/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt().decoder(jwtDecoder);
}`
```

and for the form login authorization flow:

```
@Configuration
@Order(1)
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfigFormLogin extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
 protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http .requestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/view/**"))
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/view/login").permitAll()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/view/login-successful", true)
        .and().logout()
                .logoutUrl("/view/perform_logout")
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/view/login");

    }
```

These two `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`-s make it possible to separate those two authorization flows.

As far as  Spring Security 5 resource server supports only JWT or Opaque tokens ( [see here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#oauth2resourceserver) ) it requires additional configuration. [Here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth2-jws-jwk) is a detailed description of such a configuration for Spring Security 5 resource server.